# I want to show occupied slots and available slots of interviewer from users table for a day and for remaining week by selecting date time

Tags: sql, postgresql, retool

I am not an expert in writing postgresql queries, need some help in here.

I am using a tool to make a dashboard [retool.com](https://retool.com/).
I have 2 tables users and interviewers. A user is an interviewer as well as interviewee. When users **id** is saved as **interviewer_id** in **interviews** table he is considered as **interviewer**, in the same way when the user id is saved as **interviewee_id** he is considered as **interviewee**. **start_time** column in **interviews** saves the interview start time. **interviews_slots** column in users table has the interviewer slots in json form.
see the sample data here.

`

```
{
  "monday": [
    {
      "start-time": "09:00",
      "end-time": "17:30"
    }
  ],
  "tuesday": [
    {
      "start-time": "09:00",
      "end-time": "17:30"
    }
  ],
  "wednesday": [
    {
      "start-time": "09:00",
      "end-time": "17:30"
    }
  ],
  "thursday": [
    {
      "start-time": "09:00",
      "end-time": "17:30"
    }
  ],
  "friday": [
    {
      "start-time": "09:00",
      "end-time": "17:30"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my sql statement.

```
SELECT users_tbl.id, 
  users_tbl.name,
  (select name from users where id = interview_tbl.interviewee_id) as interviewee,
  interview_tbl,start_time,
  interview_tbl.duration,
  interview_slots,
  concat(users_tbl.interview_slots->'monday'->0->'start-time',' - ', users_tbl.interview_slots->'monday'->0->'end-time')
    as Monday,
  concat(users_tbl.interview_slots->'tuesday'->0->'start-time',' - ', users_tbl.interview_slots->'tuesday'->0->'end-time')
    as Tuesday,
  concat(users_tbl.interview_slots->'wednesday'->0->'start-time',' - ', users_tbl.interview_slots->'wednesday'->0->'end-time')
    as Wednesday,
  concat(users_tbl.interview_slots->'thursday'->0->'start-time',' - ', users_tbl.interview_slots->'thursday'->0->'end-time')
    as Thursday,
  concat(users_tbl.interview_slots->'friday'->0->'start-time',' - ', users_tbl.interview_slots->'friday'->0->'end-time')
    as Friday,
  concat(users_tbl.interview_slots->'saturday'->0->'start-time',' - ', users_tbl.interview_slots->'saturday'->0->'end-time')
    as Saturday,
  concat(users_tbl.interview_slots->'sunday'->0->'start-time',' - ',users_tbl.interview_slots->'sunday'->0->'end-time')
    as Sunday
  FROM users as users_tbl
  JOIN interviews interview_tbl
  ON users_tbl.id=interview_tbl.interviewer_id 
  AND interview_tbl.created_at >= CURRENT_DATE;
```

I want to query out the data based on the interview **start_time**
suppose a interview is set for Tuesday i.e **20th Dec at 10:00 am** for 1 hour, i need to display a interviewer is available slots for Tuesday like

*consider the sample data is used to display*

| Interviewer | Tuesday occupied slots | Available Slots |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Batman | 20th Dec at 10:00 am | 9:00 - 10:00, |
|  |  | 11:00 - 17:30. |

Again in need to display similar data for the whole current week.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the user & interviewer tables, and the INSERT / SELECT statements you've written for them.

Comment: @J_H I have updated the question with select statement.